# Jython compiler is not working

Tags: java, jython, .class-file

I am using Jythonc to compile `*.py` files into `*.class` files. However, whenever I try to compile the files from the command line, it gives this error :

```
Required packages:
  java.lang

Creating adapters:

Creating .java files:
  StringParser module
    StringParser extends java.lang.Object

Compiling .java to .class...
Compiling with args: [';e:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk1.7.0_04\\bin\\javac', '-cla
sspath', 'E:\\Program Files\\jythonRelease_2_2alpha1\\jython.jar;;.\\jpywork;;E:
\\Program Files\\jythonRelease_2_2alpha1\\Tools\\jythonc;E:\\Program Files\\jyth
onRelease_2_2alpha1\\.;E:\\Program Files\\jythonRelease_2_2alpha1\\Lib;E:\\Progr
am Files\\jythonRelease_2_2alpha1', '.\\jpywork\\StringParser.java']
1  java.io.IOException: Cannot run program ";e:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_04\b
in\javac": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified

Consider using the -C/--compiler command line switch, or setting
the property python.jythonc.compiler in the registry.
ERROR DURING JAVA COMPILATION... EXITING
```

I understand that it's got something to do with jythonc not finding javac, but even something like `jythonc -C <my jdk path> foo.py` gives the same error. I tried googling, but nothing is clearly written abput setting the compiler path. Any ideas? Thanks in advance!